# Questions regarding creating the ipa file from the IOS app through the Ad Hoc certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

My team created an Ad Hoc certificate for testing a newly developed app. During that process, we have removed the privileges of a certain group of people from the certificate. However, we found some of these people within this removed group is still able to download the app after the creation of the certificate.

We want to completely remove their access to download the app, through either (1) modifying the local certificate or specification, or (2) modifying the certificate from the developers’ back-end.

Here’s a couple ways that what we tried (none of them seems to work):

(1) Modify the certificate directly, remove the privileges of a certain group of people from the certificate.

(2) Recreate the certificate, then remove the privileges of a certain group of people from the certificate.

(3) Delete the local certificate, then either modify or recreate the certificate, and try to remove the privilege to modify of a certain group of people from the certificate.

(4) Delete the certificate through the “account -> view details” option in the XCode Editor, removing the privileges to modify of a certain group of people from the certificate.

(5) Modify the privileges of a certain group of people in the XC Ad Hoc

We found that when wrapping up with the new certificate in the code sign step, the XC Ad Hoc is still added. In addition, the XC Ad Hoc is not modifiable. We believe that is the reason why this group of people still has the access to download the app.

In summary, I’m wondering if anyone knows what is the right way to stop access for a certain group.

Comment: Please confirm which certificate is used while creating ipa file.

Comment: How are you distributing the app? Through TestFlight / iTunesConnect, though your own system or through a 3rd party service like HockeyApp?